# How to set the environment variable of zerobrane studio

Tags: lua, luajit, torch, zerobrane

I install all [torch](http://torch.ch/) package into my local file torch-distro(Followed by this [tutorial](https://github.com/soumith/torch-distro)). I want to use `Zerobrane` to debug my code. `Zerobrane` can't find my local path of torch. How Can I set my local path to the `Zerobrane` environment variable.
I tried to add path.lua = "${prefix}/torch-distro/install/bin/luajit" into the user.lua. But it can't work

Comment: On which OS are you? On Ubuntu 14.04 [this](http://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging.html) works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following method works on linux platform:

1. Configuring  the luajit interpreter by adding following code into the user.lua

   `path.lua = "your_path/luajit"`
2. Configuring the envrioment variable by adding following code into the /opt/zbsstudio/lualibs/mobdebug/mobdebug.lua

   package.path = package.path .. ';my_path/?/init.lua'
   package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';my_path/?.so'

Answer (score 0):

(These instructions are for the Windows version of Torch, but the steps should work for Linux/OSX versions assuming the paths are modified).

Let's say the Torch is installed in `C:\Program Files\Torch`, then to get it running as the external interpreter from ZeroBrane Studio (ZBS), you need to add `path.lua=[[C:\Program Files\Torch\bin\torch-lua]]` to `<ZBS>\cfg\user.lua` configuration file.

Now, when you execute a Lua script from ZBS (`Project | Run` or `F6`), it will run inside the Torch environment:

```
local torch = require 'torch'
local data = torch.Tensor{
   {68, 24, 20},
   {74, 26, 21},
   {80, 32, 24}
}
print(data)
```

However, there are few more steps required to get the debugging to work on Windows (these steps are likely not be needed on other systems, but I haven't tested debugging there). ZBS is using luasocket, which is compiled against `lua51.dll`, but Torch is using `libtorch-lua.dll`, so loading luasocket into your (Torch) process is likely to crash it. To make it work, you need to build a proxy DLL and put it into your `Torch/bin` folder.

To build the proxy DLL, you will need Visual Studio C++ or mingw/gcc compiled and can follow these steps:

1. Get `mkforwardlib.lua` (VS) or `mkforwardlib-gcc.lua` (mingw/gcc) script from [Lua Proxy DLL3 page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDllThree).
2. Run `lua mkforwardlib.lua libtorch-lua lua51 X86`; if everything goes well, this will produce `lua51.dll` file in the current folder.
3. Copy `lua51.dll` file to `Torch\bin` folder.

Now you should be able to debug Torch scripts by using `Project | Start Debugging`.